# Activar ubicación geográfica en Android

Tags: google-maps, gps, android-manifest

¡Muy buenas tardes! Quiero que al pulsar un determinado botón en mi aplicación se muestre un cuadro de diálogo en que se avise al usuario de que es necesario habilitar la ubicación y en caso de que seleccione sí, esta se active automáticamente.

Tengo el siguiente código que he sacado googleando:

En el manifest declaro que voy a usar la ubicación:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.silent.miapk">

    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

El resto de código se encuentra ubicado en una de las activitys que es donde se encuentra también el mencionado botón:

```
//buscar cafeteria
    val buscaCafeteria = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?z=20&q=cafeteria")
    val CafeteriaIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, buscaCafeteria)

//Permisos ubicacion
    val coarsePermision = PermisionRequester (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        onRationale = { Toast.makeText(this, "Debes activar la ubicación para poder hacer búsquedas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() },
        onDenied =  {Toast.makeText(this, "Si quieres usar esta función deberás activar la ubicación manualmente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()})


override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
```

En el onCreate programo la acción del botón en cuestión:

```
//boton para buscar cafeterias
        cafeteriasButton.setOnClickListener{
            coarsePermision.runWithPermission{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Mostrando las mejores cafeterias... ¡Haz caso a las reseñas!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                try {
                    startActivity(cafeteriaIntent)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    // Define what your app should do if no activity can handle the intent.
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Ha habido un error al abrir Google Maps",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
```

Y por último creo una clase en la que indico que debe solicitar dichos permisos para poder activar la ubicación:

```
//Permisos ubicación
class PermisionRequester(
    activity: ComponentActivity,
    private val permission: String ,
    private val onRationale: () -> Unit = {},
    private val onDenied: () -> Unit = {}
){
    private var onGranted: () -> Unit = {}
    private val permissionLauncher =  activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){ isGranted ->
        when {
            isGranted -> onGranted()
            activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission) ->
                onRationale()
            else -> onDenied
        }
    }
    fun runWithPermission(body: () -> Unit){
        onGranted = body
        permissionLauncher.launch(permission)
    }
}
```

El código funciona llegando a solicitarnos si queremos habilitar los permisos y aceptando dicha advertencia he comprobado que la aplicación guarda este permiso e incluso llega a abrir google maps con la búsqueda deseada cuando pulsamos el botón asignado a dicha función. El problema es que **NO SE ACTIVA LA UBICACIÓN EN EL TELÉFONO** en el momento que nos solicita los permisos, ni tampoco una vez se han habilitado si reabrimos la aplicación. He probado tanto en el emulador de Android Studio como en dos teléfonos físicos y el resultado es el mismo. ¿Podeis echarme un cable por favor? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

**No se puede activar la geolocalización programaticamente, el usuario lo debe realizar manualmente ya que es un permiso que el usuario concede**, puedes en cambio abrir la pantalla de configuración para que el usuario lo realice, usando un intent:

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
```

Answer (score 0):

No es posible activar la ubicación del teléfono mediante código. Una posible alternativa sería informar al usuario de que debe activar la ubicación manualmente para usar esa función, y enviarlo a la pantalla de ajustes del teléfono para que él la active.